# Multitouch toggle button Javafx not working

Tags: java, javafx, multi-touch

I seem to have problems getting several ToggleButtons work simultaneously on different touchevents. Is there a way to use this ToggleButton class for multitouch?? When I dont add them to a toggle group I can switch 1 at the time on/off. Not several at once. In case this is not possible I was hoping to find an alternative.

Comment: Haven't worked with touch events in javafx before, but the issue could be the touch points getting grabbed somewhere (probably at the scene) and therefore delivering the is done only to the event target that grabbed the touch points. Try consuming touch events somewhere and/or ungrabbing touch points...

Comment: Thanks i will take a look at it.